# Send data to all connected clients with interval. Flask-socketio

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, real-time, flask-socketio

I am creating an online game with Flask on backend. 
I have following code on client:

```
socket.on('get_update', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

On server-side, I need to send `online_players`(dict) to all connected clients with some interval(ex. 0.5 sec)
How I can do this with Flask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use celery periodic task](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) with Flask-socketio.
Create a periodic task which will run every second or 0.5 seconds in the background.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible using `threading.Timer`. Similar to JavaScript's `setTimeout` it runs a function after `n` seconds. In the target function call `start` on the target again to run it periodically.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects

```
timer1 = threading.Timer(5, foo)

def foo():
    print("foo")
    timer2 = threading.Timer(5, foo)
```

To run `foo` immediately without waiting for 5s, replace the 1st line as:

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=foo)
```